# When I open the model, the default option selected does not remain selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I open the model, the default option selected does not remain selected, it is showing blank value.

You can check my code below:

**this is the response**

```
var getres = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

profilecountry = document.getElementById('profile_country');
$(profilecountry).append('<option value="-">Select Country</option>');

for (var i = 0; i < getres.Response.length; i++) {
    profilecountry.options[profilecountry.options.length] = new Option(getres.Response[i].vcountry_name,getres.Response[i].pk_countryid);
}
```

**This is the HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 m-t-20 pad-0">
     <select name="country" id="profile_country" class="form-control">

      </select>
</div>
```

**Output**

[Click here to see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaGCj.png)

Comment: please try to add executable code snippet

Comment: other option are coming from response, that's why i have not use code snippet

Comment: You can still make a snippet - just setup an example 'response'

Comment: There isn't a "blank" option in your code - so you've not provided us with all of the code - either you're starting with a blank option or one of your responses is blank.   That's why a snippet to show the issue is so valuable - in making the snippet you'll probably find the problem (ie that you're adding a blank option in your code but not here).   Your code works fine as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/v24n0cLf/  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: Slightly off-topic - if you're going to use jquery then you should embrace it - there's a horrid mix of jquery and vanilla javascript in your code that makes it harder to read / maintain than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this...

```
'<option value="">Select Country</option>'
```

You need to remove just "-" from value.

Comment: ya i only need to remove "-" .  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have default value like below,

```
'<option selected="selected" value="-">Select Country</option>'
```

This will show you Select Country as default select option in the dropdown.